# How do you programatically authenticate to a web server using NTLM Authentication with apache's commons httpclient?

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm using this code, and I get the stack trace that is listed below.
I've got this working with just https and with basic authentication, but not ntlm.

```
HttpClient client = null;
HttpMethod get = null;
try
{
  Protocol myhttps = new Protocol("https", ((ProtocolSocketFactory) new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory()), 443);
  Protocol.registerProtocol("https", myhttps);
  client = new HttpClient();
  get = new GetMethod("https://tt.dummycorp.com/tmtrack/");
  Credentials creds = new NTCredentials("dummy", "dummy123", "host", "DUMMYDOMAIN");
  client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
  get.setDoAuthentication(true);
  int resultCode = client.executeMethod(get);
  System.out.println(get.getResponseBodyAsString());
}

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1591)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:187)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:181)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:975)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:123)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:516)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:454)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1096)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:623)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.dummycorp.teamtrack.TeamTrackHack.main(TeamTrackHack.java:38)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:251)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:234)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:158)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.EasyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(EasyX509TrustManager.java:104)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:967)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:139)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:316)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:178)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:250)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:246)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:446)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:133)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:112)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:117)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpClient does not fully support NTLM. Please have a look at [Known limitations and problems](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Known_limitations_and_problems). The HttpClient documentation regarding NTLM is a bit confusing, but the bottom line is that they do not support NTLMv2 which makes it hardly usable in this regard.

NTLM is supported by standard java HttpURLConnection ([link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4626557)), but HttpClient has some advantages over jdk's HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Note that the current version (4.2.1) of HttpClient does claim to support NTLMv2. See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html for more info.

Comment: The most current version at this time is 4.3.3.  I have used it with NTLM authentication and it works as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the utility posted [here](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target).

It solves different problem, namely the absence of the certificate, whereas you have invalid certificate installed, but probably its verbose output about installed certificates could be helpful.